# Cut Off Edge Particles?

Tags: particles

I've added a particle system to my odject. The particles follow the normal orientation. I was wonder if there is a way to limit them from hanging off the edge? My approach right now is to convert to geo, then cut them off. I tried using a collision with kill particles, on a box bigger than the object. It didn't seem to work. I'm really hoping there is a better approach. Thank you! :D

I have attached a test project. [Link to greeb_test.blend](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4TguvcrwWRXQzFmampIWkdZdkk)

Edit: In the interest of full disclosure... This my current method to trim up the edges.

1) add particle system to object.

2) convert particles to object (apply visual transform)

3) select the new objects and join them together using ctrl + J

4) add decimate modifier to cut down on lag.

5) use boolean or knife tool to edit object and cut off unwanted pieces.

[image: greeb_test.blend]

Comment: Could you include a .blend file?

Comment: Here is a link to a test project  https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4TguvcrwWRXQzFmampIWkdZdkk  Thank you :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to find a way to cut the edges off, but I was able to find a decent substitute: **Weight Painting**. This is the result I produced:

[image]

With your mouse in the 3D viewport, key *Tab* to enter edit mode. Key *W* and select *Subdivide* 3-5 times (the more the better, until it lags to much).

Next, key *Tab* followed by *Ctrl + Tab* to enter weight painting mode. Go to the *Tools* bar. Make sure *Weight:* is set to 1. Paint a streak down the middle of the lateral faces and a dot on each end by dragging the mouse while holding the left button down. Your result should look something like this (mirrored on the hidden sides):

[image]

**Note that I moved the emmission time to 5 frames so that I could paint in peace.**

Lastly, go to your particle system settings, the *Vertex Groups* drop down and the *Density:* option. Select *Group* (it should be the only group there). Here is the modified .blend file. I might fiddle with the painting and size of the emitted particles to get a nicer looking result.

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you very much for taking the time to find a solution. :D

Comment: Glad to help! ...even if I couldn't do it exactly.